# Library for TOTP in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, one-time-password

I am currently working on some client - server app. I need to make auth process more secure, so I want to use TOTP. Client app is written in phonegab, so I need some stable and reliable library for javascript. I have found some on github, and aerogear-otp-js from jBoss Community.

Aerogear-otp-js looks good, but its only initial release so I do not think that's good idea to use it productional enviroment. Also I need to setup interval beetween keys,and that is not an option in aerogear.  So can you recommend me some good library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the AeroGear JS devs. The JS OTP lib is just getting started, but we have both Android and iOS libs that are more mature and since you are using cordova/phonegap it's possible to create a plugin to access the native libs until the JS version is a bit more solid.

-Luke